# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner engine is not started. Unable to execute task

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i tried an update of the sonarqube Server. 
Now i get an error when i'm trying to scan my project with the ant task.
The error is "**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner engine is not started. Unable to execute task.**"
The Ant Task was succesful on my old Server (6.1), on the new one (6.5) it failed. So i tried to downgrade to 6.4, but the error still remains.
So i downgraded to 6.3 and the error disappears.
My question is, does anyone know about this error? And how can i solve it?

Comment: the big question is, which sonnar scanner version for ant are you using? - not familiar with sonar and ant - but it is maybe a crucial information

Comment: I use SonarQube Ant Task version:2.5 and the scanner which comes with the server... so 6.5 and 6.4.
Now i changed my ant script to use the other sonar scanner with an exec call <exec executable="sonar-scanner.bat">.
This type works for me.. <
So the ant task <sona> still have an error, but i found an solution for me with the exec call. ;)

Comment: maybe you should also post this into https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube - can be that you found a bug :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a misleading error message. I faced this error when I added Authentication to my server i.e. force authentication for every user.
If you have added authentication recently too, then you need to make sure that you are passing the sonar.login property through your scanner.
You may create a "build" user, generate its token and pass it to the sonar job.

[This](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) is how a token can be generated.